# List Property is empty in HTTPPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Before I initialize the view, I add empty ViewModels to a List. These ViewModels need te be editted in the view by the user. If the user enters values and presses submit, the list is empty in the HTTPPost method.

I Already tried using multiple @HTML.HiddenFor() Statements. But the list keeps being returned empty.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateGuestsView(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel)
    {
        BookingStepTwoViewModel VM = new BookingStepTwoViewModel()
        {
            AmountOfGuests = bookingViewModel.AmountOfGuests,
            Date = bookingViewModel.Date,
            HotelRoomId = bookingViewModel.HotelRoomId,
        };
        VM.InitGuests();   

        return View(VM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateGuestsView( BookingStepTwoViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("CreateGuestsView", "Booking", model);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class BookingStepTwoViewModel
{

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<GuestViewModel> Guests { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfGuests { get; set; }   
    public int HotelRoomId { get; set; }

    public void InitGuests()
    {
        Guests = new List<GuestViewModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfGuests; i++)
        {
            Guests.Add(new GuestViewModel());
        }
    }

}
```

The View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Voer gasten in";
}
@model HotelDeBotelSite.Models.ViewModels.BookingStepTwoViewModel

<h2>Voer de gegevens over de gasten in</h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="box banner">

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("CreateGuestsView", "Booking", Model))
    {
        //  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Guests)

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Guests.Count(); i++)
        {
            int counter = i + 1;
            <div class="page-header">
                <h3>Gast @counter </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Guests[i].Name, "Naam")
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guests[i].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Guests[i].PostalCode, "Postcode")
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].PostalCode)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guests[i].PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Guests[i].adress, "Straatnaam")
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].adress)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guests[i].adress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Guests[i].housenumber, "Huisnummer")
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].housenumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guests[i].housenumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Guests[i].addon, "Toevoeging")
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Guests[i].addon)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guests[i].addon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        }
        <button type="submit">volgende stap</button>
    }
</div>
```

The GuestViewModel Class:

```
   public class GuestViewModel
{
    private Guest _guest;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het opgeven van een naam is vereist")]
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _guest.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _guest.Name = value;
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het opgeven van een postcode is vereist")]
    public String PostalCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _guest.PostalCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _guest.PostalCode = value;
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het opgeven van een straatnaam is vereist")]
    public String adress
    {
        get
        {
            return _guest.adress;
        }
        set
        {
            _guest.adress = value;
        }
    }

    public String addon
    {
        get
        {
            return _guest.addon;
        }
        set
        {
            _guest.addon = value;
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het opgeven van een huisnummer is vereist")]
    [Range(1,20,ErrorMessage = "Tussen 1 en 20")]
    public int housenumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _guest.housenumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _guest.housenumber = value;
        }
    }


    public GuestViewModel()
    {
        _guest = new Guest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the parameters in the using( @html.beginForm) statement.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("CreateGuestsView", "Booking", Model))
```

Becomes:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
```